# find shortest path from all vertices to multiple vertices igraph

Tags: r, network-programming, igraph

I am trying to derive a proximity measure that uses shortest distance between all vertices in my graph and a group of vertices.

I have been able to get the shortest distance using shortest.paths().
I would like to get the corresponding paths so that I can see how the paths change when I change the edge weights. But I have not been able to do so. I have found get.shortest.path which can only get the shortest path from one vertex to a group of vertices. I do like to get it from all vertices to a group of vertices without having to rely on a for loop.

Do you have any recommendations?
A sample code you can probably run on is the following:

```
set.seed(2222)
graph <- erdos.renyi.game(50, 0.3)
# Group of vertices that I want to know the shortest paths to.
some_function_that_can_get_the_shortest_path(graph, from=V(graph), to=V(graph)[1:10])
#Currently get.shortest.paths(graph, 1, to=V(graph)[1:10]) gets me the following 
$vpath
$vpath[[1]]
+ 1/50 vertex:
[1] 1

$vpath[[2]]
+ 3/50 vertices:
[1]  1 12  2

$vpath[[3]]
+ 2/50 vertices:
[1] 1 3

$vpath[[4]]
+ 3/50 vertices:
[1] 1 3 4

$vpath[[5]]
+ 2/50 vertices:
[1] 1 5

$vpath[[6]]
+ 2/50 vertices:
[1] 1 6

$vpath[[7]]
+ 3/50 vertices:
[1] 1 3 7

$vpath[[8]]
+ 3/50 vertices:
[1]  1 35  8

$vpath[[9]]
+ 3/50 vertices:
[1]  1 14  9

$vpath[[10]]
+ 3/50 vertices:
[1]  1 22 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try subsetting the graph with `induced.subgraph` to split the set of vertices you want to analyze and apply `distances` or `shortest_paths`, for example:

```
set.seed(2222)
graph <- erdos.renyi.game(50, 0.3)
subgraph<-induced.subgraph(graph,c(1,5,19))
subgraph2<-induced.subgraph(graph,c(20,38,50))
v1<-V(subgraph)
v1<-as.vector(v1)
v2<-V(subgraph2)
v2<-as.vector(v2)

distances(graph,v1,to=v2)

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    2    1
[2,]    2    0    2
[3,]    1    2    0
```

or just use `get.shortest.paths`

```
> get.shortest.paths(graph, v1, to=v2)
$vpath
$vpath[[1]]
+ 1/50 vertex:
[1] 1

$vpath[[2]]
+ 3/50 vertices:
[1]  1 12  2

$vpath[[3]]
+ 2/50 vertices:
[1] 1 3



$epath
NULL

$predecessors
NULL

$inbound_edges
NULL
```

Comment: I can already get the shortest distance. To me, I would like to get the shortest path. I think I'll put an output of get_shortest_path since I may not have been clear enough.

Comment: I think to compare the changes in the shortest paths when the edge weights varies so you need to make two graphs: the original weight graph and the change weight graph and calculate for each one the shortest paths and see how they change.  Look the output using `get.shortest.paths` in the subsetting graph, hope it be useful.